# When should I include the BSD-3 license since it's not explicitly included in the releases?

Tags: quill

I downloaded the latest release (1.3.7) and noticed it only included the copyright notice and a link to the main site in the quill.js and quill.css file.
Do I need to append the BSD-3 license information to the file(s) since I might intend on doing short-term modifications?

Comment: I see a `LICENSE` file.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the releases I have downloaded do not contain a license file however there is a clearly stated BSD-3 license on the github repo. What I wish to know is if the BSD-3 license information should be included since the release only has the copyright at the top of the files and not the entire BSD-3 information.

Comment: The release I downloaded has a LICENSE file. Which one did you download?

Comment: I grabbed 1.3.6 from the main site (think that needs to be updated) and 1.3.7 from Github, neither zips have a license file.

Comment: The 1.3.7 copy I just downloaded from Github has a LICENSE file.

Comment: The releases page https://github.com/quilljs/quill/releases has 3 options. 
I'm specifically referring to the quill.tar.gz option which is the same one that's given on the official site. The source code versions do have the license file.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that one has no LICENSE file. I suggest asking on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/